# Is there a way to turn an input into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

I am trying to make an average calculator so that you can input as many numbers as you like and I am trying to turn an input into a list, how can I do this? Here is my code that I have so far.

```
numbers = []
divisor = 0
total = 0

adtonum = int(input("Enter numbers, seperated by commas (,): "))
numbers.append(adtonum)

for num in numbers:
    divisor += 1
    total = total + num
    print(num)

print("Average: ")
print(total / divisor)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
adtonum = input("Enter numbers, separated by commas (,): ")
numbers = [int(n) for n in adtonum.split(',')]
```

Here, we split the line up by the delimiter (in this case a comma) and use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to construct the list of numbers -- converting each of the numbers in the input string into integers one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
# assign values using unpacking
divisor, total = 0, 0     

# list comprehension
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("Enter numbers, separated by commas (,): ").split(',')]

for num in numbers:
    divisor += 1
    total += num
    print(num)

print("Average: ")
print(total / divisor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval function:

```
numbers = eval(input("Enter a list of numbers i.e; values separated by commas inside '[]' "))
```

Comment: But this really places a lot more burden on the user to get the input format right. Also, `eval` should be a last resort rather than a primary method -- especially when simpler methods exist.

Comment: Yes, but it is still one of the methods which could be used.

Comment: Yep, sure its definitely valid, just pointing out the potential pitfalls with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
divisor = 0
total = 0

adtonum = (input("Enter numbers, seperated by commas (,): "))
numbers = adtonum.split(',')

for num in numbers:
    divisor += 1
    total = total + int(num)
    print(int(num))

print("Average: ")
print(total / divisor)
```

**Explanation:**
As you were trying to get the input from the user but the input provided by the user couldn't be parsed into `int` because it contained `,`.
I simply got the input from the user, splited the input at commas. Note that `split` function returns a list of elements seperated by the character provided as the argument. Then i iterated over this list, parsed every element as `int` which is possible now. Rest is same.

Comment: It would be better to use `sum(lst)/len(lst)` where `lst` is `input()` converted to a `list` of `int`s

Comment: Actually in my answer, i just wanted to show him how to get the input from the user properly as that was the main problem with his code. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval()` function here, like this-

```
numbers = list(eval(input("Enter numbers, seperated by commas (,): ")))
```

Since the input is just comma-separated numbers thus, the `eval()` function will evaluate it as a tuple, and then the `list()` function will convert it into a list.